# Laptop keeps restarting after sleep with SanDisk Ultra II 960GB

Tags: windows-10, ssd, sleep

I'm having issues with my new SanDisk Ultra II 960GB SSD in Asus Q550LF laptop running Windows 10: laptop keeps resetting after being woken up from sleep.

Looking in Windows event log, sleep event is actually missing. This event was logged while I used HDD which came originally with the laptop.

I installed SanDisk SSD dashboard and everything seems ok. Firmware is up to date. I've disabled HIPM in Power Options as suggested in another forum.

Any hints what could resolve this before I try to sell this SSD or send it back to SanDisk?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the BIOS and this resolved the problem.